# How can I enable next button only if either one of the radio button is checked?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, radio-button, required

i have a website which displays some questions to users, each questions has 4 options in radio buttons, my code looks like below:

```js
$('div.question').hide().first().show();

$('a.display').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var that = $('div.question:visible'),
        t = $(this).text();

      if (t == 'next' && that.next('div.question').length > 0) {
        $('div.question').hide();
        that.next('div.question').show()
      }
  });
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="question bg-white p-3 border-bottom">
  <div class="d-flex flex-row  question-title">
    <h3 class="text-danger">1. </h3>
    <h5 class="mt-1 ml-2">I try to be with people.</h5>
  </div>

  <div class="ans ml-2">
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" name="q1" value="1" type="radio">
      <input class="form-check-input" name="q1" type="radio" value="2">
      <input class="form-check-input" name="q1" type="radio" value="3">
      <input class="form-check-input" name="q1" type="radio" value="4">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<a id="display" class="btn btn-info btn-sm display si">next</a>
```

this is what i did, but the problem is user can go to next question without checking radio button, i want to restrict that, user should check any of the radio button to proceed to next question, can anyone please tell me how to accomplish this, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way is adding events on the html and hiding the button at the beginning.

```
<input class="form-check-input" name="q1" type="radio" value="1" onclick="handleClick(event);" />
<input class="form-check-input" name="q1" type="radio" value="2" onclick="handleClick(event);" />
<input class="form-check-input" name="q1" type="radio" value="3" onclick="handleClick(event);" />
<input class="form-check-input" name="q1" type="radio" value="4" onclick="handleClick(event);" />
```

js.

```
$("#display").hide();
function handleClick(e) {
  //console.log(e.target.value);
  $("#display").show();
}
```

Comment: this is only working with 1st question,

Comment: @ZNO I don't know how the other question are, maybe the `next` have the same class name.

Answer (score 0):

I've hide the "next" with `style="display:none;` and added this javascript-code to the end:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.form-check-input').click(function(){
    $('#display').show();
  });
</script>
```

so the "next" will be displayed as soon as the user clicks on one of the radio-buttons.

The complete version reads

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="question bg-white p-3 border-bottom">
  <div class="d-flex flex-row  question-title">
    <h3 class="text-danger">1. </h3>
    <h5 class="mt-1 ml-2">I try to be with people.</h5>
  </div>

  <div class="ans ml-2">
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" name="q1" value="1" type="radio">
      <input class="form-check-input" name="q1" type="radio" value="2">
      <input class="form-check-input" name="q1" type="radio" value="3">
      <input class="form-check-input" name="q1" type="radio" value="4">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<a id="display" class="btn btn-info btn-sm display si" style="display:none;">next</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.form-check-input').click(function(){
    $('#display').show();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: can u please edit my code and show, its little confusing